# Why TypeScript can not infer type of recursive function

Tags: typescript

I have the following example code:

```
//Derived type of sum ([head, ...tail]: number[]) => any
let sum =
    ([head, ...tail]: number[]) => head ? head + sum(tail) : 0
let x: string = sum([1, 2, 3]);
alert(x);
```

Why TypeScript infers return type of `product` to be `any`? Flow reports an error for this [code](https://flowtype.org/try/#0DYUwLgBAzgrgthAvBAFAbQBYgIYBMA0AdMWNgJbAC6AXAHbwBGIATmpQJRIB8EWeA-Lxy4IAamjwUpCp2oQADAChQkAB7UoYZmVoBzJBLjoAjPgBM+AMwcA3EA) which, I believe, is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an issue ([Recursive functions are inferred to have return type `any`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3336)) about this from June 2nd 2015, and it was closed as "by design" saying:

> We briefly had a spec that outlined how this could all work in theory,
>   but it didn't make it to implementation.
>   The current rule is that any function that sees itself during the
>   resolution of its return type is any. This seems to be good enough in
>   practice, since it's always possible to add the needed type annotation
>   and most functions aren't recursive like this due to tail call
>   optimizations not being part of the ES spec yet

So basically, just declare the return type:

```
let sum =
  ([head, ...tail]: number[]): number => head ? head + sum(tail) : 0

let x: string = sum([1, 2, 3]); // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20sum%20%3D%0A%20%20(%5Bhead%2C%20...tail%5D%3A%20number%5B%5D)%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%20head%20%3F%20head%20%2B%20sum(tail)%20%3A%200%0A%0Alet%20x%3A%20string%20%3D%20sum(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Type%20'number'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'string'))